# Issue while trying to load a custom view from XIB inside a UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift3, storyboard, xib, uipagecontrol

am trying to load a custom view from XIB inside a UIPageControl, but getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, when it is trying to instantiate the view. Pls guide me on where am I going wrong.

Here is my code:

I have a VC, where I have a scroll view and a page control, added via storyboard. I want to load a view with different data inside the page control, depending on the page.

**Custom XIB**:

I have a custom xib, which has a view and some labels and image view added on top of the same, with constraints. The xib file is updated to use custom view class, and the outlets are mapped too.

**Custom View**:

```
import UIKit

class EventPageControl: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var eventIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDescLabel: UILabel!


    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {

        let pageControl = UINib(nibName: "EventPageControl", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return pageControl
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods

    // Performs the initial setup.
    fileprivate func setupView() {
        let view = viewFromNibForClass()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
        ]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    // Loads a XIB file into a view and returns this view.
    fileprivate func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        //let bundle = Bundle(forClass: type(of: self))
        //let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "EventPageControl", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

}
```

**Viewcontroller**:

```
    func configureScrollView() {
        // Enable paging.
        var scrollWidth : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20.0
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        // Set the following flag values.
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.scrollsToTop = false

        // Set the scrollview content size.
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth * CGFloat(totalPages), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

        // Set self as the delegate of the scrollview.
        scrollView.delegate = self

        // Load the view from the xib file and configure it properly.
        for i in 0...(totalPages - 1) {

            //let eventPageControl = EventPageControl.instanceFromNib()
            let eventPageControl = EventPageControl.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))

//            update the event icon and event desc properties of the custom view here

            // Set its frame 
            eventPageControl.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * scrollWidth, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

            // Add the test view as a subview to the scrollview.
            scrollView.addSubview(eventPageControl)
        }
    }
```

**Exception**:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line `let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView` in the custom view code function - viewFromNibForClass()

When I try to use `let eventPageControl = EventPageControl.instanceFromNib()`, instead of `let eventPageControl = EventPageControl.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))`
, in the view controller, it shows the view inside the page control, but am not able to get a handle to the properties inside the custom view, so that I can update them here, in the view controller.

Pls help me on fixing the problem. Pls let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @BaSha, can you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add a private instance of the custom view in the viewcontroller? Would that enable you to access the view's properties..?

Something like `private let instanceOfEPC = EventPageControl()`

Comment: I tried changing as below, in the configureScrollView method, but it gives same exception, at the same line number.                               
//let eventPageControl = EventPageControl.instanceFromNib()
            let eventPageControl = EventPageControl()
            //let eventPageControl = EventPageControl.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))